# Issue selecting off-screen item in DOM (both in real device & simulator)

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.uitest

We are automating IOS application using xamarin.uitest in simulator and real device. We want to select a value from free drop down which is last item (visible only when scroll) but unable to scroll and select. We tried below methods.

```
app.Tap(query => query.All().Marked("Dutch"));
app.ScrollDownTo(c=>c.Css("#firstname")) Scrolling down to Css("#firstname")
app.Tap(c=>c.Marked("Dutch"));
```

Answer (score 0):

now we able to scroll and click "Not Visible" item. In order to work we are using Recursive method which accepts input(what we want), it searches in current screen if not it clicks on last visible screen so it moves down and again it will search.